# Storing multiple time series in a python pandas dataframe efficiently

Tags: python, pandas

I got different time series. Each time series contains different attributes, which have data entries at different points of time (timestamps). Each time series is labeled and has a label attribute.

I made a graphic showing the structure of the data.

[image]

It is important to me to have a structure which is persistable as a csv. I tried this with nested dataframes, but the nested dataframe is not saved correctly.

The dataset is about 250 Megabytes, stored in a numpy array of dimension (3, 1200, 2501, 10).

I am looking for an efficient approach to create such a dataframe with the given data structure, such that it is persistable with pandas and file size still efficient.

Edit:

The file format does not necessarily need to be csv.

Comment: [In my exp] Well Pandas or CSV isn't made for hierarchical data storage. If we still want to store it that way, a simple thing would be to keep single single measure files on to the disk and rebuild the df whenever needed? Atleast I would try this as my 101. Also did you try grouping by the measure_k column and then dumping that as JSON?

Comment: I would also be happy with another file format. I will add it to the question.

Comment: Are you fine if we repeat that measure_k col equal to Time_n? Then we can cache it easily at some extra space overhead. Pandas would be happy then. Interesting question!

Comment: I am open for any solution which makes this workable and persistable.

Comment: Can you try something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17349574/pandas-write-multiindex-rows-with-to-csv ; Basically you just specify the Index cols back if you don't want to go for the hacky solution. NB Be careful if you have null values.

Comment: I will try this. If you put this up as an answer I'd be happy to accept your answer, as soon as I could try it again.

Comment: Just checking, What did you go with then? Thanks!

Comment: I went with what you suggested, it works. But I also went with pickling the dataframe, which preserves quite everything I need :)